# How do I loop through a set of number multiple times while removing numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning about loops and I am currently having a hard time wrapping my head around a circular loop. Imagine there are 10 people in a table tagged with numbers 1 to 10. I want to eliminate people starting with a certain person lets say 2 and keep eliminating the person one space away from the last eliminated person (in this case 4). I also have to account for the blank spaces left by the eliminated people.

Naturally I tried to make it a list and remove elements until one element was left

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

then used lst.remove() to remove the items. Is there a more efficient way to tackle this problem?

If I were to start with person number 2, then the last person standing would be 5. I apologize if I have no input on this problem. I just need to know how I can loop and remove from a circle without losing track of where the current eliminated person is.

Comment: Add your current approach as well

Comment: Can you also include an expected output?

Comment: Is this the Josephus circle, by any chance? Because the question does feel slightly off

Comment: I'm not sure about the Josephus circle. But I'm given n and k where n is the number of people in the table and k is the starting number

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] (first person 2 dies)

[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] (one space apart from person 2 dies, so person 4)

[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] ( then person 6)

[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10] (then person 8)

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10] (then person 10 and since its a circle one space apart person 10 is person 3)

[1, 5, 7, 9]

[1, 5, 9]

[5, 9]

[5]

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing.

Here is an example:

Say you have 10 people.

> people_id = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Now let's say you want to delete the 4th person (i.e. id=3) and every second person after that until the person with id=8.

> del people_id[3:8:2]

Read more about list slicing here:

https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/

Comment: This isn't what OP wants, and is also an inefficient idea to achieve that

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yes you are right. The question has been edited and the meaning of what was being asked has changed after I gave a response.